# How to configure BizTalk server with active/passive sql cluster

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I've installed BizTalk 2013 Standard on a dedicated server. SQL is set up as an active / passive cluster (there are 2 virtual machines set aside for this) i.e. SQLDB1, SQLDB2. Now while configuring BizTalk, do I need to mention SQLDB1, SQLDB2 or cluster DNS name? If cluster DNS name, then how do I find this?

Comment: Have you already created your Failover cluster group? When clustering your SQL server, you need to specify your cluster name. For some screenshots and a guide, you can use this excellent blog post: https://pellitterisbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/configuring-biztalk-server-infrastructure-in-high-availability-on-microsoft-azure-iaas/

Comment: The whole process is well documented at MSDN, you can start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634519(v=bts.70).aspx.  Yes, you would use the cluster name to reach the database and it's a good idea to give that a DNS Alias we well.

Answer (score 1):

From [Clustering the BizTalk Server Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634455(v=bts.70).aspx)

> **Procedures for Clustering the Databases**
>
> Make sure you meet the following prerequisites before you start
>   clustering the BizTalk Server databases. When you create the domain
>   groups for your BizTalk Server environment, you must create global
>   domain accounts.
>
> Configure the SQL Server cluster before you install and configure
>   BizTalk Server. For more information about clustering SQL Server 2008
>   R2, see Getting Started with SQL Server 2008 R2 Failover Clustering
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=156820).
>
> If you are also clustering the master secret server, configure that
>   server first. For more information about high availability for
>   Enterprise Single Sign-On, see [High Availability for the Master Secret Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634572(v=bts.70).aspx).
>
> **To run the BizTalk Server Configuration Wizard**
>
> 1. Install BizTalk Server 2010 on a runtime server.
> 2. Launch the BizTalk Server Configuration program. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010, and then click
>      BizTalk Server Configuration.
> 3. To apply a custom configuration, follow the steps in Working with the Custom Configuration Manager
>      (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=156822) in BizTalk Server
>      Help. To specify the SQL Server cluster for the BizTalk Server
>      databases enter the **name of the SQL Server cluster** in the
>      Databases dialog of the configuration.
> 4. Complete the BizTalk Server configuration by following the instructions in Custom Configuration
>      (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=156823) in BizTalk Server
>      Help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch "Cluster Administrator" on any one of the SQL Server nodes i.e. SQLDB1 or SQLDB2
2. Take a look at the SQL Cluster group properties and see what the "Network Name" is.
3. If you hadn't provided a network name prior to now, you should do so now.
4. This is the name you should use to connect to your SQL cluster. You could test this out using SQL Management Studio to be sure.

Best of Luck